# Interactive JFreeChart in jsp page

Tags: java, jfreechart, linechart

I was able to create a Line Chart using JFreeChart in the jsp page. I am JFreeChart newbie wondering if we can be able to make this chart interactive in JSP page. I have searched google and found few links seem to use swings and make them interactive. Please guide me in a right direction if this is possible or let me know if there are any alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

There's support for HTML image maps in the [API](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/index.html), but you'll get a *much* more appealing result deploying a rich Swing application via [*Java Web Start*](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you mean by interactive. If you need a chart that changes it's data in response to other controls on your page take a look at CeWolf (http://cewolf.sourceforge.net/). It will generate whatever chart you want using java server-side and serve it up to the client browser as an image. If you want to be able to click on the chart to interact with the dots and lines then drop jFreechart and stick to something done client side in javascript.